# Updating the GNU/Linux Kernal to send n number of TCP packets per packet

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am using a Debian based distribution( Linux Mint 18). I want to make changes to the operating system to send n number of outgoing packets per TCP/IP packet. It would be best if the method does not involve recompiling the kernel.

Further not so much related information that answers why I want to do this.
My problem is that under certain network conditions, packets are dropped. This is a very specific network control method where some , not all, outgoing packets are dropped. In this case sending n duplicates of original packet solves the problem. I have stated one application only. But my original question might have many other applications motivated by research experiments as well.

Comment: TCP/IP guarantees, that it will detect any packet loss and resend lost packet. Why do you want to resend all packets and lower your network speed? TCP/IP will be resending only missing packets.

Comment: @RomanZaitsev its for a research purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for research is probably a userland network stack (https://www.openonload.org, netmap, ...). Otherwise, just capture packets with scapy and resend them. Iptables TEE target may also help.

Like Roman, I am also curious on why you would duplicate packets like that. There may be weird consequences, like triggering TCP fast retransmission.